# C# VSTO: Getting Latest Fill Color in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

How can one access the last-used colour in PowerPoint from within a C# VSTO Add-In?

In the example below, I am referring to the orange colour indicated by the bucket fill tool.

[image: PowerPoint Fill Dialog]

#### For Posterity

Here is the C# version of the accepted answer:

```
        var shape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1]
            .Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        shape.Select();
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("ShapeFillColorPicker");
        var color = shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB;
        shape.Delete();
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like it's highlighting the last-used color. It's highlighting the color of the currently selected shape, which will be the last used color if you've just changed the color. So perhaps what you're looking for is the fill color of the currently selected shape.

Comment: I found this property by playing around in the VBA window. So it's VBA. But perhaps it will get you in the right direction: `ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Fill.ForeColor`

Comment: Thanks a lot - that works for getting the colour of the selected shape. However, PowerPoint does keep a handle on the most recently used fill/stroke colours - which can be re-applied by hitting the paint-bucket icon (not the associated dropdown menu).  This is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than prowling the XML, which may or may not disgorge anything useful, I don't know of any way to do this via the object model, but you could draw a rectangle, invoke the button's action to color it, grab the color then delete the rectangle. Here's how you could do it in VBA:

```
Function GetColorBucketColor() As Long
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 100, 100)
    oSh.Select
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapeFillColorPicker")
    GetColorBucketColor = oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
    oSh.Delete
End Function
```

In real life it's a bit more complicated than that; the color in the ShapeFill button might be a theme color or it might be a standard RGB color; this will return the RGB value.  Setting other shapes to this color would produce the same appearance, but the shapes would no longer follow the theme.  Sometimes that matters, sometimes not.

Another potential drawback is that for this to work, something must be selected. That means that you won't be able to do it in an invisible window, and that there'll be a bit of a blip when PPT selects the newly drawn shape.

Comment: Translated into C#, this works like a charm. Thanks! For lack of a proper API to do this, this is a nice solution for my scenario. Is there a reference for commands like `ShapeFillColorPicker`?

Comment: Well, actually, these steps are reflected in the undo-history. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Re undo history: no way to change that other than perhaps closing/reopening the presentation.  To find the "magic words" to say to .ExecuteMSO, start PPT, rightclick the ribbon, choose Customize the Ribbon. Locate the command you're after and hover the mouse above it. The text in parentheses is what you're after.